# Does php-gd work with godaddy shared hosting

Tags: godaddy, shared-hosting

I was wondering if php-gd was working on godaddy linux shared hosting.

I will need to handle photos to a minimum extent so I can resize profile pictures and pictures posted.

Answer (score 3):

For more information about this you can create a file with `phpinfo();` in it, this does list every module loaded by PHP with details. You can search the GD section to see if the GD library is active and if it's the case you will find more information about it.[image]

Comment: I would say both answers could be good! I will do the phpinfo test and see :) Thank you guys.

Comment: Make sure you remove the phpinfo file after you've checked what you need. It's not a good idea to leave your server config public.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to GoDaddy: http://help.godaddy.com/article/1467

Answer (score -2):

Look here: http://developerstalk.net/web7/image-manipulation-in-godaddys-shared-hosting.aspx.
They offer to use the built in component that is usually used with the asp in the windows hosting + show you how to do it with php.
This will be far more powerful than the gd.

Comment: That page doesn't mention any built in windows/asp component that is more powerful than gd or ImageMagick. It only mentions a proprietary COM Object library called ASPJpeg that at best matches GD/ImageMagick in functionality and that the author was forced to use as a workaround to Godaddy's lack of ImageMagick. On other shared web hosts like DH, you could simply recompile PHP yourself and install ImageMagick instead of having to switch to Windows web hosting just to use a single COM extension in an Apache/PHP stack.

Comment: Mind you, I still think this is a good find (even if the OP won't be able to use it on their linux hosting), but you need to fix your description and probably include the relevant info/code samples in case the link goes down in the future.